# Gunicorn "module not found" error with Heroku (but works locally)

Tags: web, heroku, gunicorn, web-development-server

I am running a Flask app on Heroku. My project directory is like this:

```
website
 - web.py
 - render_feedback.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
```

- Now, `web.py` has a call `from render_feedback import make_graphs`
- My procfile reads: `web: gunicorn  -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT website.web:app`

But I get a `module not found` error when I try to import from `render_feedback`. Note this only happens when I use gunicorn with Heroku. This does not happen locally or when I deploy without gunicorn.

And before you ask:

- Yes, I made sure `gunicorn` is in my requirements.txt file.